# Add Radzen CSS to individual component in Blazor

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, radzen

I have an 'odd' component in my Blazor app with a Razden datagrid in it.
I use my default CSS across all components but this very one in question needs specific CSS to render properly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">
```

When I add it using _Layout.cshtml it - it works fine for my datagrid but overwrites certain styles across other components, so I need to reference this .css individually in my 'Radzen' component.

As per Microsoft recommendation I downloaded the content of this .css using dev tools and created a css file under the component like so:

```
radzencomponent.razor
razdencomponent.razor.css
```

It doesn't work though. The css doesn't seem to be picked up...

Any idea?

Comment: Ensure that in your layout you have a link to <link href="YourProjectNamespace.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />. The component level css is generated via this link. If it's not there, what you've done won't work.

Comment: Thanks @paulpitchford. Yes. I had it already added there... I tested it further and it looks like the problem is to do with the contents of radzen css file that I downloaded. I will need to strip it down line by line to see what actually causes the issue.